# Consulta INNER JOIN MySQL tarda mucho

Tags: mysql, sql, join

En un proyecto que realizo, enlisto unos registros los cuales se componen de distintas tablas, uso Inner Join para anidarlas, todo funciona, pero como son muchos registros uso una paginación, y la consulta tarda demasiado, alguien podría orientarme a mejorar mi consulta, o se debe a otra cosa. De antemano muchas gracias

```sql
select 
  totalfacturas.idtf,
  totalfacturas.foltf,
  totalfacturas.serie,
  totalfacturas.tottf,
  detalleclientes.nomdc,
  detalleclientes.fecdc 
from totalfacturas 
INNER JOIN detalleclientes ON 
 
 (detalleclientes.foldc=totalfacturas.foltf) 
  and (detalleclientes.serie=totalfacturas.serie
  and detalleclientes.nomdc = '" & nomCliente & "')
order by idtf desc
```

Comment: Que tipo de JOIN es ese ?? No deberias unir sus claves y ya ??? Te recomiendo ordenar la consulta para que acá se vea de mejor modo... el select, las columnas, el from, etc, todo en diferentes lineas para facilitar lectura.

Comment: Como ya mencionaron, el JOIN funcionaría mejor si tuvieras una indice que combine `foldc`, `serie` y `nomdc`. Sería optimo si pudieras [edit] tu pregunta y agregar la definición de tus tablas

Comment: Ahora que lo mencionan, empiezo a analizar mejor la consulta, si creo que hago una consulta extra, voy a buscar si las claves permiten unirlas.

Comment: que es nomCliente.. en serio la clave es compuesta?

Comment: a lo mejor en ese ejercicio que pide la clave son esas dos yo realice ejercicios parecidos

Comment: @gbianchi es una variable , es un programa hecho en VS

Comment: la tabla totalfacturas no tiene el campo fecha, ni el nombre del cliente, la fecha y nombre se encuentran en detalleclientes. DetalleClientes y TotalFacturas se unen con el campo foldc y foltf

Comment: Esta bien que sea una variable, pero a efectos de analizar la consulta, no importa, porque lo que va ahi es dato... Igual asi como esta, es dificil saber porque va lento.. pueden ser mil cosas...